# <router-view> can no longer be used directly inside <transition>

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <main>
    <component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
      <Transition appear>
        <RouterView />
      </Transition>
    </component>
  </main>
</template>
```

and I get this warning:

```
Use slot props instead:

<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
  <transition>
    <component :is="Component" />
  </transition>
</router-view>
```

how can I solve this without losing the layout?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace your transition :

```
<template>
  <main>
    <component :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
      <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
        <transition appear>
          <component :is="Component" />
        </transition>
      </router-view>
    </component>
  </main>
</template>
```

It works fine for me.

EDIT

You can try to wrap your element:

`Layout.vue`:

```
<template>
  <transition appear>
    <div :is="$route.meta.layout || 'div'">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

`App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    <router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
      <component :is="Component" />
    </router-view>
  </Layout>
</template>
```

Even if I'm afraid it must break the way your layout works.

Comment: I have tried this solution. It works many thanks but the transition is much less stable  and slow altough